# Unable to deploy Maven artifacts to snapshot/private Cloudbees repository

Tags: maven, cloudbees

I'm using an Ant script to deploy artifacts to my snapshot/private repository but I'm getting a Forbidden exception as follow. Looks like that the username and password are correct because if I change them I get a different error (unauthorized). What I'm missing?

```
[exec] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom:
Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact br.com.simpleconsulting.portal:portal-client:jar:6.1.0-20121007.102101-1 from/to cloudbees-snapshot (https://repository-tmoreira2020.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot):
Access denied to: https://repository-tmoreira2020.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/br/com/simpleconsulting/portal/portal-client/6.1.0-SNAPSHOT/portal-client-6.1.0-20121007.102101-1.jar, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 common causes of an unauthorized error (`403`) on CloudBees infrastructure are

- uploading with valid credentials that don't have authority to the path in question
- uploading with valid credentials to a URL path that doesn't exist

I can see that the URL path listed exists and contains new artifacts - did you get things working after you posted this question?

Comment: Hi Ben, I figured out that the problem was the missing path so I created them manually. But this should be fix on cloudbees end right?

Comment: Thiago - Alas no - the DAV provider needs to create directories explicitly, - you have to use exactly the right DAV configuration for this to occur automatically though - wagon-webdav-jackrabbit is the key - which is no longer included in the core maven configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing settings.xml explicitly to your maven commands:

mvn -s ~/.m2/settings.xml deploy

Also, ensure that you have webdav-jackrabbit extension configured in the build section of your maven pom.xml

```
<extensions>
  <extension>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
  </extension>
</extensions>
```